# AWS Cloudfront distribution ID by tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

is that possible to get aws cloudfront dist id by tag via awscli or  aws sdk for powershell. I could only get only ID by ARN number of resource

```
aws cloudfront list-tags-for-resource --resource XXX
{
   "Tags": {
       "Items": [
           {
               "Value": "TEST_APP",
               "Key": "CLIENT_APP"
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Solved via

```
cloudfrontdistids=$(aws cloudfront list-distributions | jq -r ".DistributionList.Items[].ARN")
for dist in $cloudfrontdistids
do
        if [ $(aws cloudfront list-tags-for-resource --resource $dist | jq -r ".Tags.Items[].Value") == $VALUE ]
        then
                CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID=${dist:(-14)}
        fi
done
```

Comment: I'm surprised the CLI doesnt have a simpler and more efficient way to achieve this. Couldn't find it myself either.

Comment: what's the point of tags then, if you cannot search the list by providing tag param?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65873489/is-there-a-way-to-list-cloudfront-distributions-by-tag-without-downloading-them/65873831?noredirect=1#comment116476576_65873831) is an answer if any one stumbles upon, without downloading entire list

Comment: Yes, totally, they should implement a `--filters` argument the same way as `aws ec2 describe-instances`. @BaluVyamajala's anwser works perfectly though, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by the original poster seems to be almost correct.
But the CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID is **not always 14 characters**, so in order to avoid pulling aditional characters use this instead:

CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID=**${dist##*/}**

In bash, it removes a prefix pattern. Here, it's basically giving you everything after the last path separator /, by greedily removing the prefix */