# Is there a way to list CloudFront distributions by tag without downloading them all using ListDistributions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58009093/aws-cloudfront-distribution-id-by-tag) is similar, but the only answer there is to get the list of *all* distributions and filter them locally, which is not what I am looking for.

[This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/tagging.html) hints that it might be possible to filter by tag (*"You can search and filter your resources based on the tags you add"*), but I just cannot figure out *how*!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only think of one way, since `aws cloudfront` doesn't directly support get distributions by tag.
we can use `resourcegroupstaggingapi` cli , to get ResourceARNs of all cloudfront and using `jq` and `sed` extract DistributionIds

Ex: Tag ApplicationID=APP1111

```
aws  resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tag-filters Key=ApplicationID,Values=APP1111 --resource-type-filters 'cloudfront' --tags-per-page 100 | jq -r ".ResourceTagMappingList[].ResourceARN" | sed 's:.*/::'
```

we can further use xargs and execute get-distribution for each Id.

```
aws  resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tag-filters Key=ApplicationID,Values=APP1111 --resource-type-filters 'cloudfront' --tags-per-page 100 | jq -r ".ResourceTagMappingList[].ResourceARN" | sed 's:.*/::' | xargs -I {} aws cloudfront  get-distribution --id {}
```

Comment: Hm, `aws  resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources` doesn't seem to return any Cloudfront distributions at all. [This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/tagging.html) says: *"Tag Editor and Resource Groups are currently not supported for CloudFront"*. Might that be the reason?

Comment: I have tested both the commands. it did return all the cloudfront distribution Ids with tag `ApplicationID` as `APP1111`.

Comment: I am definitely doing something wrong then. What I meant is that even *without* the filter I do not see ANY cloudfront distributions in the response from `aws  resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources`, only some `arn:aws:ec2` resources, while I obviously have some listed by `aws cloudfront list-distributions`. Would you have any idea why?

Comment: Ah, got it. Region mixup ;)  Thank you so much! Accepting the answer now!!!

Comment: Yep, indeed, I figured the region should be `us-east-1` or you won't see your distributions (probably because Cloudfront distribs are global but still need to be created somewhere and `us-east-1` is basically aws default region)

Answer (score 6):

To add to Balu's great answer, if you have specified a default region when setting up `aws-cli` and this region is **not** `us-east-1` then it won't work (you'll see an empty array of `ResourceTagMappingList`).

Be sure to add `--region us-east-1` at the end of the command like so:

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tag-filters Key=tagName,Values=tagValue --resource-type-filters 'cloudfront' --tags-per-page 100 --region us-east-1
```

Comment: This answer is still valuable at 2022/03 and save my day. Thanks @Blockost